# Is there a software that tells for how long the computer has been running on battery?

Tags: battery

There are many apps in store that will tell you how much your battery will last before the computer turns off.

I need something that tells me something like : "You unplugged at 95% and have been running for 2 hours and now have 55% "..

So like a graph in Android phones maybe?

I am using a Mac Book Pro 15 with latest Mac OS 10.9.

Comment: give us bit more about your os and hardware

Comment: @Buscar웃 done... Edited my question.

Comment: OK, thanks, now try holding the alt key and click on your battery icon, and tell me if that will do for you.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It opens up a menu shows health and percentage left and apps using battery etc.. But not the info I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OSX 10.9 and above this is all in Activity Monitor app under the Energy tab. 
It shows your battery life over the last 12 hours, and while it was plugged in is highlighted in green. It also shows you what apps are sucking on your battery and how much they are draining at the moment, and on average.

Comment: Yeah but it does not exactly say what time it was unplugged.. Thanks however.

Comment: If you want something like that, I recommend making an AppleScript that writes the the times down. 
Though the 12 hour graph in Activity Monitor is pretty comprehensive, I don't know of anything more 'consumer friendly' than AppleScript for exact times

Comment: I just saw, in that page there is "Time on Battery" just next to that graph!!! Thanks :)